# Getting a List of 5 recent items filled in UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

Getting a List of 5 recent items filled in Text Field, from where if i select any item will get populated in the Text Field. Open for any suggestions/solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Paul Peelen but his solution is incomplete. You want to have **five different** items, so the code is the following:

```
#define CAPACITY 5

[...]

self.recents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:CAPACITY + 1];

[...]

- (void)addItem:(NSString*)addItem {

    //item won't be twice in the list
    [self.recents removeObject:item];

    //recently used items are at the beginning of the list
    [self.recents insertObject:item atIndex:0];

    //remove the sixth item
    if ([self.recents count] == CAPACITY + 1) {
        [self.recents removeLastObject];
    }
}
```

Comment: true, I agree.. yours is better.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `NSMutableArray` and listen to the `UITextField`'s delegate. Whenever the user presses "Return" or the field is resigned, add the current value to the NSMutableArray (`[myArray addObject:textField.text];`)

When you want to show the data in the array:

```
for (NSString *value in myArray)
{
    NSLog(@"String value: %@", value);
}
```

Comment: Sulthan's answers is a more complete answer.